# babel-node doesn't recognize es2015?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to run the relay-starter-kit updateSchema.js with babel-node. It seems that it doesn't recognize the arrow functions:

```
> SyntaxError: .../build/updateSchema.js: Unexpected token (10:9)
   8 | 
   9 | // Save JSON of full schema introspection for Babel Relay Plugin to use
> 10 | async () => {
     |          ^
```

I've tried to add the preset "stage-0" to ".babelrc" which fix that error but instead I get:

```
SyntaxError: .../build/updateSchema.js: Unexpected token (23:1)
  21 |     );
  22 |   }
> 23 | }();
     |  ^
```

Is this not recognizing the es2015? Or is it a error in my schema? The script ["updateSchema.js"](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit/blob/master/scripts/updateSchema.js) is from the relay-starter-kit.

Everything else runs fine and "babel-node" doesn't seem to have a problem with the rest of my application which is written in es2015.

EdIT:
I've tried now to just download the relay-starter-kit and run "npm run update-schema" and it works out of the box.

Comment: I think it's because it thinks that you calling function instead declaring it. Arrow functions are anonymous, so you should remove `async`then if you want to iife the function you should wrap it with another brackets like: `(()=>{/*your code*/}());`

Answer (score 0):

Did you required `babel-core` at entry point?

First `npm install --save-dev babel-core`

then open entry point file of your application

and then required `babel-core` by `require("babel-core");`

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked on babel 5, but it should throw a syntax error because it is a non-standard arrow function call syntax: [arrow function discussion](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2027)

So, the fix is like this:

```
(async () => {
  var result = await (graphql(Schema, introspectionQuery));
  if (result.errors) {
    console.error('ERROR: ', JSON.stringify(result.errors, null, 2));
  } else {
    fs.writeFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, '../data/schema.json'),
      JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
    );
  }
})();
```